# How to find the Walrasian eqilibrium and determine the welfare?

Tags: welfare-economics

Suppose there are 2 farmers. Farmer 1 grows rice and farmer 2 grows wheat. There are 2 states of nature tomorow: rainy or sunny, both with probability 0.5. If it rains, farmer 1 grows 1 unit of rice and farmer 2 grows nothing. If it shines, farmer 2 grows 1 unit of wheat but farmer 1 grows nothing. Assume that rice and wheat are perfect substitutes and both farmers have identical utility functions $u(x+y)$.

Now suppose there is a service that provides weather forecast with accuracy $\theta\in [0.5,1]$: If the forecast says "rain", then the probability of rain is $\theta$ and the probability of sun is $1-\theta$, and vice versa. How do I find a Walrasian equilibrium as a function of $\theta$? And how does the welfare of farmers vary with $\theta$?

I know that if $\theta=1$, then there will be no trade. After computing the expected utility, the welfare will decrease. But what if $\theta\neq 1?$

What I have done so far: Suppose the forecast says "rainy". The posterior belief of the probability of tomorrow being rainy would be $\theta$, and that of being sunny is $1-\theta$. How should I proceed?